# What Update logic do I use in a ListView control?

Tags: asp.net, listview

I have a ListView control, but I bind the datasource in the code behind, so I can't use the magical automatic CRUD functionality. I've implemented Edit (which shows the relevent Edit template for that item) , and Cancel, but I don't know how to do the Update method which updates the database.

Each row contains 2 columns, name and value, so the edit template has one textbox to edit the value part.

```
protected void lvFishBiscuits_ItemUpdating(object sender, ListViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    // Logic goes here? to update 

    lvFishBiscuits.EditIndex = -1;

    BindListView();
}
```

The oldvalue property of e is null, and I need to know the unique ID of the item I am editing - should I put that into a hidden field on the row or something, or can I use the index property with the datasource?

I have a method

```
protected void UpdateFishBiscuits(int uniqueIDInDatabase, string newValue)
{
  // do the update
}
```

so it's a case of how do I call it?

Answer (score 1):

You could set the `uniqueIDInDataBase` as [CommandArgument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemcommand.aspx) of your Update-Button.

```
CommandArgument='<%#Eval("uniqueIDInDataBase") %>' />
```

and retrieve it in [ItemCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemcommand.aspx)-Event handler(CommandName "Update"). There you can also place your update-logic.

Comment: I like it! Thanks that will probably do it.

Comment: You should handle the ItemUpdating event too(without content), because you would get a "The ListView 'lvFishBiscuits' fired event ItemUpdating which wasn't handled" or something like that otherwise.